# How to setup webpack for @import ~stylus in vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, import, stylus

I try to import my variables.stylus in my vue component, but when i use `@import "~@themes/variables.stylus"`, webpack throw error: `failed to locate @import file ~@themes/variables.stylus.styl`

webpack config

```
alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
       themes: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/themes'),
       '@': resolve('src'),
 }

 {
     test: /\.styl$/,
     loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 5 version', 'stylus-loader']
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be like this:

```css
@import '~@/themes/variables.stylus';
```

Webpack replaces the alias `@` with the path you have in the configuration, in this case `src`. So the import becomes `src/themes/variables.stylus`.